# Ошибка 500 Bitrix

Tags: php, .htaccess, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Исправлял файлы сайта через FTP и получил 500 ошибку) Залил обратно те же файлы что были до исправления на FTP и все равно ошибка осталась, возможно проблема в .htaccess
Вот код из него

```
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php


<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag allow_call_time_pass_reference 1
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off

  #php_value display_errors 1

  #php_value mbstring.func_overload 2
  #php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://ludacha.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ludacha.ru [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ludacha.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (.*)/index\.php\ HTTP/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://ludacha.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>
```

В админку входит отлично и файлы тоже спокойно редачатся, может слетели настройки index-ной страницы? Подскажите как исправить. Также пропали надписи http://joxi.ru/Y2Lzp7yTnDjL8r

```
    [Mon Dec 11 00:01:02 2017] [error] [client 141.8.132.35] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 00:01:06 2017] [error] [client 141.8.132.35] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 00:43:54 2017] [error] [client 181.48.9.82] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 05:56:51 2017] [error] [client 207.46.13.128] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:01:49 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.22] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:01:51 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.22] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 08:10:17 2017] [error] [client 40.77.167.42] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 09:26:31 2017] [error] [client 139.162.116.133] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 11:14:49 2017] [error] [client 157.55.39.95] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 11:19:58 2017] [error] [client 207.46.13.128] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:22:52 2017] [error] [client 164.52.7.131] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:24 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:28 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:47:28 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:30 2017] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:31 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:48:31 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:54:57 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:03 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:03 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:09 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 14:56:09 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:00 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:01 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs, referer: https://109.120.136.198/var/www/ludacha/data/www/ludacha.com
[Mon Dec 11 14:57:05 2017] [error] [client 95.161.153.62] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:15 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:16 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:16 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:17 2017] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `ludacha.ru' does NOT match server name!?
[Mon Dec 11 15:21:17 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze19 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.16 OpenSSL/0.9.8o configured -- resuming normal operations
```

error_log за 11 число ( когда произошла ошибка )

Comment: @AK добавил error_log

Comment: Раскомментируйте строчку #php_value display_errors 1 в htaccess. Может, покажет ошибка где

Comment: @Юрий_Смирнов не показала(

Comment: Вы бы лучше конфиг Апач показали, почему у вас там нету файла /etc/apache2/htdocs?

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка 500 может быть связана с очень обширными причинами ее возникновения. Для того, чтобы решить данную проблему - обратитесь к вашему хостинг провайдеру, они посмотрят логи и сообщат вам о том, в каком именно файле она возникла.

Если вы хотите самостоятельно исправить ошибку 500 - найдите на своем хостинге файл error_log. Там можно посмотреть логи и тем самым определить истинную причину возникновения данной ошибки.

Подробнее о причинах и исправлениях ошибки 500 можно почитать [по этой ссылке](https://www.darkstack.pro/blog/500-internal-server-error).

Comment: собственно, к вопросу данный «ответ» вообще не имеет отношения. единственный различимый смысл его появления — ссылка на статью.